# How to determine best packaging for the fewest number of boxes needed?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to do this...the code below works, but I am having to do several queries inside a double while loop, which, to me, doesn't seem to be the best approach.

The problem:  I have a series of lots with various number of units within each lot.  I need determine the total number of boxes needed to package a maximum of 50 units per box, without splitting a lot into two different boxes.  I need to have a list that contains the Box ID, Lot Number, and the number of units in that lot.  If the total number of units between all lots within that box is less than 50, then an additional row for XX individual dummy units needs to be added to bring the total up to 50 units.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
   SYSID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   LOT_NUMBER NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   UNIT_COUNT BIGINT NOT NULL,
   BOX_ID BIGINT NULL,
   PROCESSED BIT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #temp
(
   LOT_NUMBER,
   UNIT_COUNT
)
VALUES
('0111590',2),
('0111944',18),
('0111978',5),
('0111982',15),
('0111985',15),
('0111995',14),
('0111996',34),
('0111997',29),
('0111998',16),
('0111999',17),
('0112001',26),
('0112002',29),
('0112004',17)


DECLARE @BOX_ID BIGINT
DECLARE @SYSID1 BIGINT
DECLARE @SYSID2 BIGINT
DECLARE @SYSID3 BIGINT
DECLARE @UNIT_COUNT BIGINT
SET NOCOUNT ON

SET @BOX_ID = 1

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE BOX_ID IS NULL) > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 1 @SYSID1 = t.SYSID, @UNIT_COUNT = 50 - t.UNIT_COUNT
   FROM #temp t
   WHERE BOX_ID IS NULL
   ORDER BY t.UNIT_COUNT DESC

   UPDATE t SET
      t.BOX_ID = @BOX_ID
   FROM #temp t
   WHERE SYSID = @SYSID1

   WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE BOX_ID IS NULL AND PROCESSED IS NULL) > 0
   BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 1 @SYSID2 = t.SYSID
       FROM #temp t
       WHERE t.BOX_ID IS NULL
         AND t.PROCESSED IS NULL
       ORDER BY t.UNIT_COUNT desc

       SELECT TOP 1 @SYSID3 = t.SYSID, @UNIT_COUNT = @UNIT_COUNT - t.UNIT_COUNT
       FROM #temp t
       WHERE t.BOX_ID IS NULL
         AND t.UNIT_COUNT <= @UNIT_COUNT
       ORDER BY t.UNIT_COUNT desc

       UPDATE t SET
          t.BOX_ID = @BOX_ID
       FROM #temp t
       WHERE t.SYSID = @SYSID3

       UPDATE t SET
           t.PROCESSED = 1
       FROM #temp t
       WHERE SYSID = @SYSID2
   END

   INSERT INTO #temp
   (
       BOX_ID,
       LOT_NUMBER,
       UNIT_COUNT
   )
   SELECT @BOX_ID, 'DUMMY UNITS', @UNIT_COUNT
   WHERE @UNIT_COUNT > 0

   SELECT @BOX_ID = @BOX_ID + 1

   UPDATE t SET
      t.PROCESSED = NULL
   FROM #temp t
   WHERE BOX_ID IS NULL

END

SELECT 
  BOX_ID,
  LOT_NUMBER,
  UNIT_COUNT
FROM #temp 
ORDER BY BOX_ID,UNIT_COUNT desc
```

The output of this code

```
BOX_ID  LOT_NUMBER     UNIT_COUNT
1       0111996        34
1       0111998        16
2       0111997        29
2       0111944        18
2       0111590        2
2       DUMMY UNITS    1
3       0112002        29
3       0111999        17
3       DUMMY UNITS    4
4       0112001        26
4       0112004        17
4       0111978        5
4       DUMMY UNITS    2
5       0111982        15
5       0111985        15
5       0111995        14
5       DUMMY UNITS    6
```

Thanks for any recommendations,
jlimited

Comment: Have you used <your favorite search engine> to search for: `t sql most efficient packing`? Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: Also have you considered not performing these kinds of calculations in T-SQL? Seems like OO would be more optimized at this (and probably plenty more code examples already out there, too).

Comment: @jlimited - I'm really curious, please... what did you end up doing about this?  Did you continue using the working code you posted.  If not, what did you use?